# Original derivation of Stokes' Law for the drag force on a sphere

Tags: fluid-dynamics, history, drag, specific-reference, viscosity

Where can I find the original derivation of the [Stokes' law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law) derived by Stokes himself?

Can it be shown without using dimensional analysis?

I would appreciate if someone provides the complete derivation of drag force law in all its mathematical glory, not simplified.

I have searched [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity);
[here](http://strata.uga.edu/4500/transport/stokes.html);
and the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_flow) article on the same too, but it doesn't seem to tell me what Stokes really did.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: John I wanted to know where can I find a copy or website that shows stokes work

Comment: Stokes, G. G. "On the Effect of the Internal Friction of Fluids on the Motion of Pendulums." Cambridge Philos. Trans. 9, 8-106, 1851. Reprinted in Mathematical and Physical Papers, 2nd ed., Vol. 3. New York: Johnson Reprint Corp., p. 1, 1966.

Comment: [PDF here](http://mural.uv.es/daroig/documentos/stokes1850.pdf). That took me several seconds to Google.

Comment: Related meta post: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4490/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [Stokes' Law](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Sir-George-Gabriel-Stokes-1st-Baronet)

Stokes derived his law in 1851. He was a member of the Royal Society, and the paper, if he published them there, are freely available [here](http://royalsocietypublishing.org/).

I cannot say, for sure, that he published in the Royal Society publications, but it seems likely. I have searched through fluid dynamics but there are 838 papers in total, so I ran out of time.

> Stokes’s mathematical and physical papers were published in five volumes; the first three under his own editorship in 1880, 1883, and 1901 and the last two under that of Sir Joseph Larmor. Stokes also wrote On Light (1887) and Natural Theology (1891).